# What protocol to choose for DLNA live-streaming?

Tags: java, protocols, live-streaming, dlna

I'm developing an app which should stream audio (PCM or MP3) to most DLNA-compatible receivers.
For now, I'm providing a URL to where the client can connect to (or forced to connect via the DLNA-commands) and then the audio-stream is transmitted via HTTP/TCP as MP3.

This works fine, but there is a delay of about 8-15 seconds which is a mess for my application.

I read about RTP/RTSP which might work with much less delays (~2 seconds) but this seem to be only implemented by a few DLNA-rendereres as this is not required by the DLNA-certificate.

Who can tell me what protocol I should use to be **compatible with most DLNA-renderers** & have a **most small delay** in a **local network**?

Or maybe HTTP was already the right thing and I'm doing something wrong? When I send an existing file via HTTP to my DLNA-renderer, it's not doing such large delay, but I assume this is because the file already exists and the full power of the network can be used to load it in advance?

Comment: The slowness is likely from the renderer buffering a large amount of data before starting the playback. How much data is transferred before rendering begins, and at what speed?

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I haven't count the bytes yet, but the MP3-stream is at the moment at 128kb/s and the delay about 8-15s. This should then be: 128 Kbps = 16 KB/s * 8s = 128KB.. not much. But I think the receiver is waiting until he has prebuffered a time of ~8-15seconds which will take exactly that time due to live-streaming.

Comment: Then I think you have your answer -- the delay has nothing to do with the protocol, but rather with the renderer's buffering rules, so RTSP wouldn't make any difference. You're already doing the right thing. But your renderer was not designed to provide low-latency startup of live streams.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Too bad if a less delay would really not be possible. Maybe anyone has another additional hint?

Comment: Well, one thing you could do is buffer the last 15 seconds on the server side, then "rewind" the timestamp of incoming connections by that amount, effectively blasting 15 seconds of stream immediately after connection (then dropping down to 128k). Depending on how the renderer decides how much to buffer, that might even fool it into playing immediately even with much less than 8-15 seconds. Of course, this means the output won't be as live (but I'm not sure you could get that anyway).

Comment: Haa, this is an amazing hint! I will do what I can do with this. It might be possible to simply create 15 seconds of silence, add this at the beginning of each new connection and then command the renderer to seek to 15 seconds, or so :) I will have some thoughts about that, thanks for your help so far.